# How can i make pause option in java

Tags: java, timer, pause

Now I'm using java to create Timer program.
But the problem is..
I want to add pause option in my program but i cannot find How to add pause option..
So Please give me some advice on how to insert a pause option..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter Minutes : ");
        int min = sc.nextInt();
        long sec = min * 60;
        for(long i = sec; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(i % 30 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i/60 + " min" + i%60 + " sec");
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        System.out.println("Timer is over..");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code that you want to fix? Why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: There's no problem with my code, but I just want to add a pause button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to give the user the option to enter something and cause the countdown to pause. The problem (I think) is that if you ask for input, then that will block the current thread of execution, hence your timer will freeze.

To solve this, you need some form of asynchronous execution. You might want to take a look at [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html): you can use this to schedule a callback to occur every second. This callback function could print the next number in the countdown sequence, while your main thread waits for user input and cancels the timer if the user types `pause`.

Comment: Also, another thing to consider is that waiting (sleep or timer) only guarantees to wait for *at least* the given time, it might wait a bit more (e.g. until the next time your program gets scheduled on the CPU). Therefore, if you want an accurate timer, you should query the actual system time, and check how long your thread was asleep for.

Comment: No worries! Make sure you accept the answer (green tick) if it solves the question ;)

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.

Your comment is very usefull enough to me!! :)

So do I have to use callback function with schedule as stated on your link?

Is it right answer that I understand?

Comment: consider adding some example to your otherwise link only answer

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think I disagree with the need for that in this case: I don't think it's useful to write more documentation (or generic code examples) for a simple, well-documented class, and I also don't want to take away the fun of solving the problem and figuring it out (if I give a specific example).